# What is the best way to compare variables of same class?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have a class with variables for old data and new data.

Example:

```
class Person{

    String newAddress;
    int newMobileNumber;
    String newOfficeId;
    // many fields like this (atleast 15 fields)

    String oldAddress;
    int oldMobileNumber;
    String oldOfficeId;
    // many fields like this (atleast 15 fields)

    //getters and setters of all the fields.
}
```

What I am doing is on click of button storing old data and new data in a table consisting column with the same name as that of fields(for keeping track of old data)

But if all the oldFields are equal to newFields I want to avoid to avoid database operation.

one way of doing this is using many if conditions. like this,

```
if(oldAddress.equals(newAddress)){
  flag = true;
}
if(oldMobileNumber.equals(newMobileNumber)){
  flag = true;
}
```

So I'll need many such `if()` ,I don't find this solution that good. How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: i´d create a variable `Person oldPerson` in your Person class. Then i would override `equals` and check if `oldPerson.equals(newPerson)`

Comment: For address, you might want to use [equalsIgnoreCase](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm)

Comment: @sam2090 that I'd handle. it is just a rough scenario I've gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also throw away all these double values in your `Person` class and just create a Person variable that is just used to store the old values. You could just update the old values inside your setter methods. To check if any value changed you could override the equals method and compare the current object to the `olvValues` variable in your Person class.

Due to this way you will safe yourself some extra work if you are adding variables to your Person class at some point.

this could look something like this.

```
public class Person{

    String address;
    int mobileNumber;
    String officeId;
     // many fields like this (atleast 15 fields)

    private Person oldValues;

    public Person(String address, int mobileNumber, String officeId) {
        this.address = address;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.officeId = officeId;
        oldValues = new Person(this);
    }

    public Person(Person p) {
        this.address = p.address;
        this.mobileNumber = p.mobileNumber;
        this.officeId = p.officeId;
    }

    // Your method that checks if any value did change.
    public void checkIfValuesChanged() {
        if(this.equals(oldValues)) {
            // Nothing changed
        }
    }

     @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + mobileNumber;
        result = prime * result + ((officeId == null) ? 0 : officeId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof Person)) return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (mobileNumber != other.mobileNumber)
            return false;
        if (officeId == null) {
            if (other.officeId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!officeId.equals(other.officeId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // Your setter methods do save the old values in the oldValues Person object
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        oldValues.address = this.address;
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ComparisonChain class from Guava](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) to simplify boilerplate code. In your case in would be something like this:

```
return ComparisonChain.start()
     .compare(newAddress, oldAddress)
     .compare(newMobileNumber, oldMobileNumber)
     ...
     .result() == 0;
```

Though I would definitely recommend you to get rid of copy-paste as suggested by Kevin Esche. Comparison chain would be handy in that case either.

**UPD** Note that if the members of your class can be `null` than simple `oldAddress.equals(newAddress)` won't suffice because of `NullPointerException`. And if you don't want to depend on Guava you could use [Objects#equals method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) to simplify cumbersome null-checking.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add all those `if` statements once, in the overridden `Object#equals` method for your class.

You can have it automatically drafted for you in most IDEs.

You probably also want to override `Object#hashCode` along the way.

**In Ecplise**

- Right-click your class
- Click `Source` -> `Generate hashCode() and equals()`

You then compare two `Person` instances by just invoking `equals`.

Comment: so you mean in equals I should compare those fields, and call equals in a controller. right? so it the best way?

Comment: @piechuckerr that's the most elegant way. Also note that `equals` may be invoked implicitly in collections, which may help you as well. I'd also suggest documenting your criteria for equality well, which will get you a long way when tweaking code issues.

Comment: I will make changes in equals() but do I have to make any changes in generated hashcode() method?

Comment: Your `hashCode` implementation needs to conform to the `equals` / `hashCode` contract. You can look some of that info online - the simplest way is to look at [Object#hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) (and `equals` just below).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to define a class Contact and compare an old contact with a new contact using the standard equals method

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {

@Test
public void myTest() {
    Contact oldContact= new Contact("A",1,"A");
    Contact newContact= new Contact("A",1,"A");
    System.out.println(oldContact.equals(newContact));
}   

}


class Contact{
String newAddress;
int newMobileNumber;
String newOfficeId;


public Contact(String newAddress, int newMobileNumber, String newOfficeId) {
    super();
    this.newAddress = newAddress;
    this.newMobileNumber = newMobileNumber;
    this.newOfficeId = newOfficeId;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Contact other = (Contact) obj;
    if (newAddress == null) {
        if (other.newAddress != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!newAddress.equals(other.newAddress))
        return false;
    if (newMobileNumber != other.newMobileNumber)
        return false;
    if (newOfficeId == null) {
        if (other.newOfficeId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!newOfficeId.equals(other.newOfficeId))
        return false;
    return true;
}


 }
class Person{

Contact newContact;
Contact oldContact;
public Person(Contact newContact, Contact oldContact) {
    super();
    this.newContact = newContact;
    this.oldContact = oldContact;
}

}
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question I don't have two objects. it's only one object with new and old fields.

Comment: Ok sorry for misunderstanding